# Running a script with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

For learning purpose, I'm trying to install and setup my own Kubernetes Cluster on GCP.

I want to provision my instances on GCP with a bootstrap script.

Here is my `google_compute_instance` config

```json
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
    name = var.vm_name
    machine_type = "f1-micro"
    zone = "europe-west1-b"

    boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
            image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
        }
    }

    network_interface {
        network = var.network
        access_config {
            // Include this section to give the VM an external IP address
        }
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        script = var.script_path
        connection {
            type        = "ssh"
            host        = var.ip_address
            user        = "root"
        }
    }

    tags = ["node"]
}
```

I have this issue when I do `terraform apply`

> Error: Failed to open script 'sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install 
> apt-transport-https 
> ca-certificates 
> curl 
> gnupg-agent 
> software-properties-common 
> zsh 
> vim
>
> curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key
> add - sudo add-apt-repository \    "deb [arch=amd64]
> https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \    $(lsb_release -cs) \
> stable" sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docker-ce
> docker-ce-cli containerd.io
>
> curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo
> apt-key add - cat <<EOF | sudo tee
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/
> kubernetes-xenial main EOF sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y
> kubelet kubeadm kubectl sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl ':
> open sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install 
> apt-transport-https 
> ca-certificates 
> curl 
> gnupg-agent 
> software-properties-common 
> zsh 
> vim
>
> curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key
> add - sudo add-apt-repository \    "deb [arch=amd64]
> https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \    $(lsb_release -cs) \
> stable" sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docker-ce
> docker-ce-cli containerd.io
>
> curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo
> apt-key add - cat <<EOF | sudo tee
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/
> kubernetes-xenial main EOF sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y
> kubelet kubeadm kubectl sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl :
> no such file or directory

All my instances are created on the cloud, It's seems to find the bootstrap script but it is showing this error.

What did I miss? Is there a better way to do it ?

Here is the script:

```sh
#bin/bash

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common \
    zsh \
    vim

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Comment: You do not show the script. Does your script begin with this line `#! /bin/bash`? Are you defining your startup script correctly in the metadata: https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-startup-scripts

Comment: I've just added the script @JohnHanley

Comment: @Kevin, I see `!` missing in `#bin/bash`. Not sure, maybe..

Comment: I have the same issue using `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide the [private_key](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html#private_key) argument in the `connection` block of `remote-exec`.

```
private_key - The contents of an SSH key to use for the connection. These can be loaded from a file on disk using the file function. This takes preference over the password if provided.
```

A sample block could be like this:

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
        script = var.script_path
        connection {
            host     = var.ip_address
            type     = "ssh"      
            user     = "root"
            private_key = fileexists("/temp/private_key") ? file("/temp/private_key") : file("C:/private_key")             
        }
  }
```

Comment: If he is getting `Error: Failed to open script 'sudo apt-get update` error, it's only after connecting to the machine.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested, I have found an easier solution, without using ssh but by using the google metadata available at creation of the resource.

`metadata_startup_script = file("./scripts/bootstrap.sh")`

```json
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
    name = var.vm_name
    machine_type = "e2-standard-2"
    zone = "europe-west1-b"

    boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
            image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
        }
    }

    network_interface {
        network = var.network
        access_config {
            // Include this section to give the VM an external IP address
        }
    }

    metadata_startup_script = file("./scripts/bootstrap.sh")

    tags = ["node"]
}
```